# How do I change the value of a UITextfield on a UIButton click?

Tags: ios, swift

When I click my button (Randomize in this case), how would I get the text (any text) to be viewed in the UITextField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Randomize` method:

```
donorView1.text = "Pokemon 20 Years"
```

Based on the name of the method, I'm assuming you want a random text field to have the text. If so, use this as your method:

```
let textFields = [donorView1, donorView2, donorView3, ...]
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(textFields.count-1)))
let randomTextField = textFields[randomIndex]
randomTextField.text = "Pokemon 20 Years"
```

I recommend you go through some tutorials for something this basic before coming here. [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com) has lots of tutorials and most are updated.

Also, note that all properties and methods should be in lowerCamelCase. See 
[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) for information about it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a science fair due on Monday, and I've decided to take on a new language of code. I've been trying to learn really rapidly unfortunately, due to my procrastination. I really appreciate this!

Comment: @ProfessorBrandon If it worked for you, can you up vote and accept my answer? Thanks :)

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to list random variations of text in only one UITextfield? For example, if I wanted to have Pokemon, Yu-Gi-Oh, and Digimon listed in only one donor field, rather than multiple text fields, do you know how could I execute that? Ahh, this helped me so much! Thank you for everything already!

Comment: @ProfessorBrandon I'm pretty confused because I don't have all the information needed to do what you want. You should ask a separate question with the necessary information.

Comment: Apparently I can only ask one question every 90 minutes. Well, I'm looking for a way to find a more efficient way to variate my quotes onto a variety of UITextFields (in this case, donorView1, donorView2, etc.) after only one click of a UIButton. Clicking the Randomize button would result in an array of quotes, however, with this array I can only get one quote per field, but I need various quotes in each box (i.e. donorView1 would have Quote 001, 006, 003, 002 while donorView2 could have 003, 002, 006, 008). Would you know how to solve this issue, Troy? It's much appreciated :]

Comment: @ProfessorBrandon All you have to do is make an array of the quotes and then randomize it four times for each. If you ask a new question, I can show you code.